# Spring Security annotation based configuration - form based login is bypassed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security. I've been working on my hobby project which uses spring security. In my application i have REST as well as page request mapping. **I want to use httpbasic for REST and form based login for else**. I am able to popup httbasic authentication for REST but it is popping up for other requests too.
Following is my annotation based spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                new PlaintextPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        // Home, Login and Logout pages are permitted to all
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home", "/rest/denied", "/rest/ping")
                    .permitAll();


        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**")
                .hasRole(Roles.ROLE_USER)
            .and()
                .httpBasic();

        // Authorization based calls for specific roles
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/user/**")
                .hasRole(Roles.ROLE_CREATE_USER)
            .antMatchers("/rest/database/**")
                .hasRole(Roles.ROLE_DB_ADMIN)
            .and().httpBasic();




        // Only authenticated users can continue
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
            .hasRole(Roles.ROLE_USER)
        .and().
            formLogin()
                .loginPage("/divein")
                .failureUrl("/divein?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/diveout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/divein?logout")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/403");

    }
}
```

Below are the logs:

```
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/home'
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/rest/denied'
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/rest/ping'
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/rest/**'
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/rest/user/**'
18:08:37.041 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/rest/database/**'
18:08:37.042 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/somepage' matched by universal pattern '/**'
18:08:37.042 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /somepage; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
18:08:37.042 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9054b1a2: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1c07a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 09F57A48161AD5D009FAA9248907574F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
18:08:37.061 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@24c3b979, returned: -1
18:08:37.071 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /somepage]
18:08:37.083 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_38]
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/somepage' matched by universal pattern '/**'
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/somepage'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = true
18:08:37.084 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@4cb8f09c, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing text/html
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing application/xhtml+xml
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing image/webp
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing application/xml;q=0.9
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing */*;q=0.8
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Ignoring
18:08:37.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Did not match any media types
18:08:37.106 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = true
18:08:37.106 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
18:08:37.106 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.NegatedRequestMatcher - matches = true
18:08:37.106 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AndRequestMatcher - All requestMatchers returned true
18:08:37.108 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/CRMBS/somepage]
18:08:37.108 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
18:08:37.108 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@4cb8f09c, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing text/html
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/octet-stream .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/xml .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - multipart/form-data .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - text/xml .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing application/xhtml+xml
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.109 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.111 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.111 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/octet-stream .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/xml .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - multipart/form-data .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - text/xml .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing image/webp
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/octet-stream .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/xml .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - multipart/form-data .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - text/xml .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing application/xml;q=0.9
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
18:08:37.112 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/octet-stream .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - application/xml .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = true
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@24cee99e
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@1bcb91e
18:08:37.113 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
18:08:37.114 [http-bio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Wow, question from a few years but I have now kinda the same problem. I managed to configure the separated configurations but when a call to the rest api doesn't have the authentication header it goes forward to the spring-security login instead of a denyal message json

Answer (score 0):

HttpBasic in Spring Security is to set up with default standart configuration.

At this point, to learn more about how Spring Security process the requests, you can read about the Spring Security FilterChain.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html